# jQuery swipe events in Chrome running on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, swipe

During testing I noticed that jQuery swipe events do not work when a web application is running on Chrome on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean). Swipe events do work on the standard Android browser running, just not in Chrome. Is there any known workaround the make the swipe events work in Chrome on this OS?

Comment: did u get a solution for dis. am also having same issue

Comment: I did not.  Although it may be premature of me to say this, it appears that Google Chrome is more interested in generally supporting all of the various devices than they are supporting all of the web standards on the devices.  While this may be a good decision for them economically, not supporting web standards such as this hurts the entire mobile web because developers are helpless to do anything about it.  What we should be able to do we cannot except for better supported devices like Apple Safari.  It is very disappointing.